# Compiling LFE files with make

Tags: erlang, makefile, lfe

Is there a standard way of compiling `.lfe` source files from a `make` rule in an OTP project?

According to the docs, I'm supposed to use `lfe_comp:file/1`, which doesn't help much if I want to compile multiple such files in an OTP application (where I'm supposed to keep the source files in `src`, but the binaries in `ebin`).

Ideally, I'd be able to do something like

```
erlc -Wf -o ebin src/*lfe
```

But there doesn't seem to be `lfe` support in `erlc`. The best solution I can think of off the top of my head is

```
find src/*lfe -exec erl -s lfe_comp file {} -s init stop \;
mv src/*beam ebin/
```

but that seems inelegant. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On suggestion from rvirding, here's a first stab at `lfec` that does what I want above (and pretty much nothing else). I'd invoke it from a `Makefile` with `./lfec -o ebin src/*lfe`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- erlang -*-
%%! -smp enable -sname lfec -mnesia debug verbose
main(Arguments) ->
    try
        {Opts, Args} = parse_opts(Arguments),
        case get_opt("-o", Opts) of
            false ->
               lists:map(fun lfe_comp:file/1, Args);
            Path ->
               lists:map(fun (Arg) -> lfe_comp:file(Arg, [{outdir, Path}]) end,
                         Args)
        end
    catch
        _:_ -> usage()
    end;
main(_) -> usage().

get_opt(Target, Opts) -> 
    case lists:keyfind(Target, 1, Opts) of
        false -> false;
        {_} -> true;
        {_, Setting} -> Setting
    end.

parse_opts(Args) -> parse_opts(Args, []).
parse_opts(["-o", TargetDir | Rest], Opts) ->
    parse_opts(Rest, [{"-o", TargetDir} | Opts]);
parse_opts(Args, Opts) -> {Opts, Args}.

usage() ->
    io:format("usage:\n"),
    io:format("-o [TargetDir] -- output files to specified directory\n"),
    halt(1).
```

Comment: @rvirding - feel free to; that's what it's here for.

Comment: I HAVE borrowed it and added a simple lfec to the development branch. As Joe once "Robert is incapable of making small changes to anything", which is true so I rewrote it. Now I just need to work out which options are useful in an LFE context.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. LFE is not supported by OTP so `erlc` does not know about `.lfe` files. And as far as I know there is no way to "open up" erlc and dynamically add information how to process files. An alternative would be to write an `lfec` script for this. I will think about it.

Just as a matter of interest what are using LFE for?

Comment: I've posted a first stab at it. I'm mostly using LFE for fun at the moment. Certainly nothing I couldn't do with vanilla Erlang. It just looks interesting, and I'm partial to Lisp, so I'm playing with writing some simple components in it to get comfortable.

Comment: @Inaimathi OK, there is a Google group http://groups.google.com/group/lisp-flavoured-erlang with some traffic, not much. The develop branch on github has some new stuff which hasn't made it to the master branch yet.